# Summing Values date_range pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I am creating a time-lapse of the number  of tweets over a period of time.

```
timeLapse = pandas.date_range(dates[0], dates[-2], freq="1Min")
```

At the moment I am counting the occurrences of tweets.

```
z = Counter(dates)
```

I am plotting the dates as follows

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(timeLapse)), index=timeLapse)
ts= ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
plt.show()
```

The values I am using are randomly generate, my question is if there is a method for summing values already to insert as a list instead of random, or do I have to manually go through the list and sum them myself?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean here, are you trying to sum the values for a given date or tweet? Can you post code that shows your df and desired output

Comment: @EdChum dates is a list of timestamps of tweets it has over 7000 entries. Counter counts the simultaneous occurances of tweets and stores them as values. Using date_range I compress this list to 227 entries of a minute each. At the moment I am using random numbers as values, but I want to use the occurances of tweets in the minute timespan as values. TO achieve this i would have to loop through the list and count the number of tweets the occur within the minute interval manually, but ths strikes me as inefficient, so I am asking is there a built-in method that does this ?